# Is there a good way to break down the order of the centraliser in a symmetric group?

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

I recently rediscovered the rather nice formula for the order of the centraliser of a permutation in the symmetric group and its realtionship with conjugacy classes.  I wondered whether we could say anything interesting if we break down this formula as I will try to explain.

The following is very well known:  Suppose that $\sigma \in \Sigma_n$ is a permutation.  Then $\sigma$ has cycle type $(a_1,a_2,\dots a_n)$ if (when written in disjoint cycle notation) $\sigma$ consists of $a_1$ cycles of length 1, $a_2$ cycles of length 2 and so on.  The order of the centraliser of $\sigma$ is given by the following famous formula:
$$  \lvert C(\sigma) \rvert  = \prod_i a_i! i^{a_i}.   $$

By thinking of $\Sigma_n$ acting on itself by conjugation and applying Burnside's lemma it is easy to see that the expected value of the order of the centraliser,
$$  \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{\sigma \in \Sigma_n} \lvert C(\sigma) \rvert $$
is just the number of conjugacy classes in $\Sigma_n$.  This number is also known to be the number of integer partitions of the first $n$ integers.

Less well known:  Define two new (but related) functions $D,E : \sigma_n \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ as follows:
$$ D(\sigma) = \prod_i a_i ! \text{    and   }  E(\sigma) = \prod_i i^{a_i}$$
where again $\sigma$ has cycle type $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$.

Is there an interesting group theoretical/combinatorial interpretation of these functions?  Can one use this to calculate the expected value of $D(\sigma)$ or $E(\sigma)$ perhaps using a Burnside's lemma type argument?